# oracle sequence for returning number as a string

Tags: oracle, sequence

I have a sequence which returns a number like this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test.SEC_FORM 
START WITH 9000
MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
MINVALUE 1
NOCYCLE
CACHE 20
NOORDER;
```

And I created a trigger to insert this value into the table FORM.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test.TRG_SEC_FORM
BEFORE INSERT
ON test.FORM
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.FORM_ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT test.SEC_FORM.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.FORM_ID FROM DUAL;
   END IF;
END ;
```

But the sequence is returning integer while the form_id in the form table is string.
I need a string like '9000' etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: this worked for me on 11g without explicit conversion to char

Comment: Yes the issue has been resolved by using to_char(test.sec_form.nextval).

Comment: then you should mark penartur's answer as a correct one :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Why is `FORM_ID` a string, why won't you make it an integer?

2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test.TRG_SEC_FORM
BEFORE INSERT
ON test.FORM
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.FORM_ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT TO_CHAR(test.SEC_FORM.NEXTVAL) INTO :NEW.FORM_ID FROM DUAL;
   END IF;
END ;
```

Comment: +1, you forgot `3` though, "It'll be implicitly converted anyway so there's no point worrying about it"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider to change FORM_ID data type from VARCHAR or STRING to NUMBER.